# Converting date field value returned by REST API to correct date?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, date

I performed a query on this USGS feature service of Airport locations:

[Click for query](http://services.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/WFS/transportation/MapServer/1/query?where=&text=&objectIds=27431&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&f=pjson)

And the value for the field `LOADDATE` is:

```
LOADDATE: 1411380301000
```

However, when I pull the layer into ArcMap, the value is:

```
LOADDATE: 9/22/2014 10:05:01 AM
```

Does anyone know what the `1411380301000` value represents, and how to convert it back into `9/22/2014 10:05:01 AM`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked too quick. According to this [thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/19367), the `1411380301000` value is:

> ...presented as epoch milliseconds since 01/01/1970 GMT.

And I used the following code to convert it:

```
import time

value = 1411380301000
date = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(value/1000.0))

print date

>>> 09/22/2014 10:05:01
```